# C# carry old interface functions to new interface

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Similar questions were asked before, but I can't find an answer like this.

C#

```
public interface I1 { //sealed interface, cannot change
  string Property1 {get; set;}
  void OnEvent();
}
public class C1 : I1 {//sealed class, cannot change
  public string Property1 {get; set;}
  public virtual void OnEvent() {/*update property1...*/}
}
public class C2 : C1 {//my class inherits C1. Now I want I2 for my class C2
  public string Property2 {get; set;}
  public override void OnEvent() {base.OnEvent(); /*populate property2...*/}
}
```

How do I get an interface "I2" that includes `Property1` and `Property2` that I can pass around?

Comment: Also, you should be more more careful about calling a class "sealed." See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx for the meaning of the the sealed modifier. If your class was truly sealed, then you wouldn't be able to inherit from it. The same applies to the interface, but more so, because the sealed modifier isn't valid for interfaces. I'm only mentioning this because it is confusing and potentially misleading for less knowledgeable developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to do something that an interface isn't meant for. An interface is simply a contract and, when a class implements that contract, it is promising that it will fulfill it in some way or another, but the interface itself *doesn't* care since it doesn't concern itself with implementation details. If you want to pass behavior on to children, you need to subclass.

However, if you really are trying to create an interface that "carries functions" over from a parent interface, that is definitely supported and easily accomplished. All you need to do is create a child interface to inherit your parent.

Example:

```
interface IParentInterface
{
   int FirstProperty {get;set;}
   void OnChange();
}

interface IChildInterface: IParentInterface
{
   string SecondProperty {get;set;}
}

class InterfaceInheritanceGoodness: IChildInterface
{
   public int FirstProperty { get; set; }

   public string SecondProperty { get; set; }

   public void OnChange()
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

And, interfaces support multiple inheritance... Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface I2 { 
    string Property1 {get; set;}
    string Property2 {get; set;}
}

public class C2 : C1, I2 {
    public string Property2 {get; set;}
    public override void OnEvent() {base.OnEvent(); /*populate property2...*/}
}
```

Since `C2` already have an implementation of Property1 from the base class, it will be used for implicitly implementing `I2` interface.

Answer (score 1):

What about explicit implementation?

```
public class C2 : C1, I2 
{
    string I2.Property1 
    {
        get { return base.Property1; } 
        set { base.Property1 = value; }
    }
    public string Property2 {get; set;}
    public override void OnEvent() {base.OnEvent(); /*populate property2...*/}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get an interface from a class. Why can't you just use C2 by itself?

Comment: for testing purpose. we can build mocking interfaces.